# How to test events that were sent by inner transaction / delegate call?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, truffle-test, openzeppelin-contracts

Usually, using `truffle` I can check for events like this:

```
    let { logs } = await myContract.doSomethingImportant( xxx );

    // 1500 tokens are expected to get
    expectEvent.inLogs(logs, 'myImportantEvent', {
      arg1: 111,
      arg2: 'and so on'
    });
```

However, `logs` contains only the events that was fired directly inside of the contract function `withdrawVestedTokensByTimestamp`:

```
function doSomethingImportant(uint256 x) public returns(uint256) {
    // ... do something else here ...

    emit myImportantEvent(x, amount);

    return amount;
}
```

However, if in this function a token transfer will happen or another function is called, which would fire events itself, they don't appear in the logs.

Running tests with `truffle test --show-events` will list all of the expected events, but how can I catch them inside truffle test?

Answer (score 4):

Use [openzeppelin-test-helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers)

Specifically use [expectEvent.inTransaction](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers#async-intransaction-txhash-emitter-eventname-eventargs--)

I created an example in the community forum for how to use:
https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/how-to-check-for-events-that-was-dispatched-in-a-nested-operation/955/2

Comment: This is indeed an amazing library, but it comes with a caveat. It breaks compatibility with [BigNumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), due to several imports that use [BN.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/)

Answer (score 1):

The [openzeppelin-test-helpers library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers) that you are using can actually retrieve all events from a transaction. `expectEvent.inLogs(logs, ...);` actually scans `logs` for each event that was emitted during the transaction and will look for the event name (and values) that you specified.

In your case, you simply need to add another `expectEvent.inLogs(logs, ...);` to your test case that has the expected values from your other event. This will catch it and do exactly as you expect.

Additionally, since this `expectEvent` searches through all of the events in a transaction, you can actually have multiple of the same events get emitted in a single transaction. For example, if you had the line `emit myImportantEvent(x + 1, amount);` immediately after the first `myImportantEvent`, you could write a test and it would be able to pick up both of them.

Comment: But in my example, `logs` contains only the event of my own contract, not those events, that was dispatched internally thru calls to other contracts and their `transfer`-methods

Comment: Use expectEvent.inTransaction from openzeppelin-test-helpers